# Is this a tolerable amount of crashes? Would you consider 3% to be edge cases?

Tags: android, mobile, crash, crash-reports, flurry

my crash logs are reporting that approximately 3% of users have experienced crashes.

Specifically this is using "sessions" via Flurry. Out of 50,000 sessions, there have been 1500 sessions with crashes.

In an informative app, is this a tolerable amount of crashes. Would you consider 3% to be edge cases, statistical outliers, in an Xth percentile?

I would like to investigate bugs I can't replicate from devices I've never heard of, but I need to be able to rationalize if this is worthwhile.

Comment: God, I hope not.  I would expect that number to be more like a tenth of one percent or less. 3% isn't even [two-nines reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nines_(engineering)).

Comment: suggestion : count how many sessions you perform yourself (all apps included). Every 30 or so, imagine what it would be like to have it crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I'm not quite sure what "quartile" means, but this seems to suggest that app crashes are more common than I thought.  It does happen to me on occasion on my IPad.  I don't recall any apps ever crashing on my Android device, although I do recall having to re-power it a couple of times due to system instability.

Comment: thanks, I found the sources of that graph, it was helpful. yes 3% is bad